# Single PDF Viewer loading from multiple UITableView cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uitableview

I am working on a project that has a single, large UITableView, and all of the cells go to a different ViewController, each displaying a separate PDF. However, I want to consolidate it, so each cell loads a single PDF ViewController, which loads the respective PDF based on the cell that was tapped. This is the code I have so far for loading and displaying the PDF.
in the header:

```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *pdfView;
```

in the main

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *urlAddress = [[NSString alloc] init];
        urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"PDF1" ofType:@"pdf"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.pdfView loadRequest:requestObj];
    }
```

How would I amend this code to have the PDFViewController determine what cell was selected, and to load the respective PDF?
Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

In your `PDFViewController`

create a property like this `@property(nonatomic, readwrite) NSString *selectedPDFUrl`;

In your tableViewContoller 
 have a `NSMutableArray *arrayOfPDFStrings;` and add all the URLS to this array.

when ever user selects a cell 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath`copy that particular cell PDF url  into the`PDFViewController`objects`selectedPDFUrl` property;

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    PDFViewController*pdfView=[[PDFViewControlleralloc]initWithNibName:@"PDFViewControllers" bundle:nil];
    pdfView.selectedPDFUrl = [arrayOfPDfUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cards animated:YES];
}
```

After doing this you have access to the URL through this variable `selectedPDFUrl` ;

so you should do something like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        NSString *urlAddress = [[NSString alloc] init];
        urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:selectedPDFUrl ofType:@"pdf"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: selectedPDFUrl];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.pdfView loadRequest:requestObj];
    }
```